# How to use absolute paths in SAPUI5's ODataModel?

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I want to use absolute paths in my SAPUI5 application in order to access a single resource directly.

According to http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/de/6c/47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2/content.htm it should work.

But when I use something like:

```xml
<Text text="{users>/Users('123')/LastName}" />
```

It cannot fetch the data.

Has anyone a clue what is wrong here?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the path is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a parameterized path to a property, it seems that the value doesn't get loaded automatically.

To get access to the object defined by the parameter, you could specify an [element binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) for that object on your control and then reference the property in a relative way:

```xml
<Text binding="{users>/Users('123')}" text="{users>LastName}" />
```